nginx producing a 404 when adding a new site
I've configured nginx to host a website at website.com, blog.website.com, but now when I make a new config in /etc/nginx/sites-available - it wont allow me to access content in the path: website.com/statz .
It HTTP 404's, and the error/access log I have defined dont have anything in them.
What may be going wrong?
For brevity I am showing all (3) configs for website.com, blog.website.com, and website.com/statz.
website.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /home/path/to/website;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

blog.website.com
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/usr/website/blog;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  blog.website.com;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

not working website.com/statz
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
}
server {
    server_name website.com; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;

    root /home/usr/statz/; 

    index index.php;

    location /statz/ {
    alias /home/usr/statz;
    }

    ## only allow accessing the following php files
    location ~ ^statz/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; # if your Nginx setup doesn't come with a default fastcgi-php config, you can fetch it from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/fastcgi.conf
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404; # protects against CVE-2019-11043. If this line is already included in your snippets/fastcgi-php.conf you can comment it here.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # prohibit httpoxy: https://httpoxy.org/
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock; #replace with the path to your PHP socket file
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # uncomment if you are using PHP via TCP sockets (e.g. Docker container)
    }

    ## deny access to all other .php files
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## serve all other files normally
    location /statz {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ## disable all access to the following directories
    location ~ ^statz/(config|tmp|core|lang) {
        deny all;
        return 403; # replace with 404 to not show these directories exist
    }

    location ~ /statz\.ht {
        deny  all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ statz/js/container_.*_preview\.js$ {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control 'private, no-cache, no-store';
    }

    location ~ statz\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        allow all;
        ## Cache images,CSS,JS and webfonts for an hour
        ## Increasing the duration may improve the load-time, but may cause old files to show after an Matomo upgrade
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ ^statz/(libs|vendor|plugins|misc|node_modules) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## properly display textfiles in root directory
    location ~statz/(.*\.md|LEGALNOTICE|LICENSE) {
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}

The logs are empty, and when I visit website.com/statz - it http 404s. I am trying to setup matomo but the config provided is not working in my case (https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/matomo.conf)
What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much
